# How to save/import .shp file data to a PostGIS table in Java

Tags: postgis, shapefile, java, geotools

Ok, I've searched and at a loss as to why I cannot find anything on how to save a shapefile to PostGIS with Java. Thought GeoTools might be helpful, but doesn't seem to be there either.

So here's the scenario and functionality that I've been looking for.

1. User uploads a file
2. Java code (Spring) on the server side get the file and checks to see if it is a .shp file
3. If it is a .shp file, save it to a PostGIS table

It's step 3 that doesn't seem to be out there and what I'd like to find a solution for. In my case the table will have all necessary fields and a couple of other fields to record who uploaded and when etc..

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need a [`ShapefileDatastore`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html) to import your shapefile (remember to make sure you have at least 4 files and upto 13 at last count) then you create a [`PostGISDatastore`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html) to write the features from the first store to.

You will need to include `gt-shapefile` and `gt-jdbc-postgis` in your `pom.xml`. Then if you study this [tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html) you will see how reading and writing features works.

If you are in a hurry, you can probably cut and paste from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54556180/439194).

Comment: Thank you Ian, I guess it's just not as straight forward as I'd hoped. That's a big help thank you. It looks like I've got some learning to do. I figure this would be a fairly easy thing to do. I guess not so much. Thanks again.

Comment: That's about as straightforward as anything is with spatial data.

Comment: Another quick question. I have this code running, but it creates a table for each shape file that is saved. This seems strange to me, but other similar examples do the same kind of thing. Is there a way to specify a common "geometries" table for storage of all shape/spatial data? Or is this just way too complicated, given the complexity of these?

Comment: depends, are all of your attributes associated with the geometries the same? if so you can stuff the lot into the same table (just skip `createSchema`)

Comment: Thank you Ian, you have been incredibly helpful. I can't be sure that all attributes will be the same, no. I was hoping that there could be a common "geometries" table that held all shape file contents. So if one wanted to save multiple different types of shape files in a database, you would have to create a table for each? That doesn't seem practical or manageable.

Comment: In general each table contains a set of related "features" (geometry + attributes) each type of feature is then stored in a separate table. If you have a lot of datasets that all use the same geometries then you could use a single geom table and many data tables that are joined - but you probably don't have shapefiles in that case

Comment: Thanks again for you advice. If I understand what you are saying, it seems strange to say, but it sounds like saving shape files into a database isn't practical. Especially if there are a number of different users and all have different shape files. Something just doesn't seem to jive. I'm thinking of converting the shape files into geoJSON and saving those instead.

Comment: I don't think I understand what your issue is? any way the same code will work for GeoJSON just change the output datastore. You might need to ask a new question that describes what you are actually trying to do

Comment: I've changed the code and already have it outputting the features as geoJSON and I'll save that to the database instead. Thank you for the code examples and your help. I will have to sort out the rest of it another time.

Comment: Is PostGISDatastore an actual class? And are you having this datastore write shape file data directly in the data base? And if yes, how is the shape file data stored?